# Getting post data from ajax request php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, null

I keep getting null values with the below code:

Ajax request:

```
formData = {
            u: "3959eeadb32e02b85a792e21c",
            id: "6d7613df26"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/includes/loginProcess.php",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                
            }
        });
```

PHP Processing:

```
$data = array();
    $data['u'] = $_POST["u"];
    
    $data['id'] = $_POST["id"];
    echo json_encode($data);
```

{u: null, id: null} is logged in the success function. Any ideas?

This is on an AWS Lightsail instance BTW... is there some server config I'm missing maybe?

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json'` is wrong. You aren't sending JSON. Just remove this line and it should work fine. Also `crossDomain: true` almost certainly isn't needed here (and probably doesn't do whatever you think it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

is wrong. You aren't sending JSON. This will confuse the server. Just remove that line and it will work fine.

(Also `crossDomain: true` almost certainly isn't needed here (and probably doesn't do whatever you think it does)).